# Put single and double quote in Python string format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble figuring out how to print a very specific line.

I tried using .format and I also tried the print("str",variable,"str") method but I can't seem to figure out how to make it print correctly.

```
feet=5
inches=6

print('Room Length:{}' {}"'.format(feet,inches))
```

I want the computer to print; Room Length: 5' 6"
but I am not sure how to print this while keeping the apostrophe and the quotations for feet and inches.

Comment: Use slash: `Room Length:{}\' {}"'.format(feet,inches))`

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, you're right ! didn't notice that those were the markers for the inches and feet. Deleted my comment as it was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('Room Length:{}\' {}\"'.format(feet,inches))
```

Comment: No need to escape the ``"``, though it does not hurt either.

Comment: I thought, being explicit is better.

Comment: Update to new f-strings if you want: `print(f'Room Length: {feet}\' {inches}\"')`